# Material UI makeStyles() and withStyles() added too many <style> tags inside the <head>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I recently started using Material UI library for my react projects and i found it super useful until i noticed those `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` section. Whether i use `makeStyles()` or `withStyles()` i noticed that they add so many `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` and increase the size of the html file, the more styling you do the more `<style>` tags they add. My question is very simple- Wouldn't the browser take more time to download our html file? and since our styles are not in a separate CSS file there won't be any **caching** by the browser right? Is there any solution so that i could get rid of these too many `<style>` tags? or should i just follow my previous styling approach - 1 CSS file for each component which in the end gives me one main CSS file.

Comment: They are dynamically generated by the JS, so have absolutely 0 incidence on html size.

Comment: @dbuchet thanx for this valuable information, i wasn't aware of it. But wouldn't it mean that it will take more time for the browsers to apply our css? first downloading the JS file and then adding the style tags dynamically?

Comment: Your browser needs to download JS files anyway to run your react app. So it's faster to apply css from your already downloaded JS files, than loading one more external CSS file